# How to prevent abusive crawlers from crawling a rails app deployed on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, robots.txt

I want to restrict the crawler access to my rails app running on Heroku. This would have been a straight forward task if I was using Apache OR nginX. Since the app is deployed on Heroku I am not sure how I can restrict access at the HTTP server level.

I have tried to use robots.txt file, but the offending crawlers don't honor robot.txt.

These are the solutions I am considering:

1) A `before_filter` in the rails layer to restrict access.

2) Rack based solution to restrict access

I am wondering if there are any better ways to deal with this problem.

Comment: "most of the offending crawlers don't honor robot.txt"??  i think it is "all".  if it is offending, then probably "robot.txt" = ignored file

Comment: I have read about honeypot solutions: You have one URI that must not be crawled (put it in robots.txt). If any IP calls this URI, block it. I'd implement it as a Rack middleware so the hit does not go to the full Rails stack.

Comment: @Wukerplank, that is an interesting solution. Will you post this comment as an answer so that I can up-vote? Do you have links to the articles?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have read about honeypot solutions: You have one URI that must not be crawled (put it in robots.txt). If any IP calls this URI, block it. I'd implement it as a Rack middleware so the hit does not go to the full Rails stack.

Sorry, I googled around but could not find the original article.

Comment: +1. Here is the original article that made the suggestion: http://www.madirish.net/?article=224